# Wavy text inside of UIBezierPath in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgpath

I saw a trekking app on Android which built routes on selected criteria. It also could built routes for provided gpx-files. All those routes were very wavy. And above each highlighted route I could see its name — also as a very wavy text moving along with the highlighted path, repeating all the curls and waves. I wonder how it is possible to create the same effect in iOS.

What I have is a gpx-file. Shortly speaking, it's just a very long array of tuples:

```
typealias Coordinates = (Double, Double) // x and y
let points: [Coordinates] = [ (120, 120), (130, 135), (135, 125), (138, 122) ]
```

Coordinates are represented by pixels, and I use catmull rom interpolation algorithm to build UIBezierPath with smooth rounded corners.

I can draw a wavy text by changing angles for each letter in a playground. But calculating all that transformation stuff for an array of pixels looks too complicated.

Probably there's a better solution?

Comment: There is some code in SVGgh (available on GitHub), which I wrote, which positions glyphs along a (fairly) arbitrary CGPathRef. This might be useful for you although the problem is what if the text is longer than the path, and some paths will make for ugly results.   Look for +(void) positionGlyphs:(NSArray*)listOfGlyphs alongCGPath:(CGPathRef)pathRef in SVGgh/SVGgh/SVGRenderer/GHGlyph.m

Comment: I'll take a look, tnx.